Background modes in Flutter project IOS (Android Studio)
I'm developing an iOS app in Flutter, but I'm having trouble enabling Background Mode.
I added the following configuration to Info.plist and Runner.entitlements:
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>processing</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>location</string>
</array>

However, the Background Mode option doesn't appear in my App ID to be enabled.
enter image description here
And the build fails with the message: Provisioning profile "Ready Response ios_app_store ..." doesn't include the UIBackgroundModes entitlement.
How can I enable this option in my App ID?
Note: I'm using Android Studio and publishing through Codemagic.
I also tried to edit the project.pbxproj file manually with the help of the gpt chat, but the build continues to fail with the message: "Provisioning profile
doesn't include the UIBackgroundModes entitlement".
